# Ionic: ion-item with fixed label and paragraph

Tags: html, css, ionic-framework, ionic2

Is possible create three `ion-item` like these using Ionic Framework?

[image]

No problem with the first one (standard `disabled ion-input` with `fixed label`). I have some issue with the second one which contains a `fixed label`, a `<p> tag` in the middle and a `right button`.
The last one, also, a `fixed label` and a `button` with a `paragraph` in the middle content.

Can anyone help me?
Thank you

Comment: yes it is possible you can use the grid system, and it is also possible inside ion-item check out the scss of ionic `start` `end` ...
if you still need help you need to post some code, what did you achieve till now.

Comment: @George Are there known issues using `ion-grid` inside `ion-item`? If not, I think this is the most flexible solution for custom alignment.

Comment: i do not think there is any issues with it, but i am not entirely sure, you have to try it

Comment: if you are obliged to use ion-item, i believe using item-end and item-star as addweb suggested is better

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about what you want, but I think it is similar to what you want.

```
<ion-content padding>
<ion-list>
  <ion-list-header disabled="true" ><ion-label color="primary">Disabled</ion-label><ion-label >Item Disabled</ion-label></ion-list-header>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-icon ios="ios-close" md="md-close" color="primary" item-end></ion-icon>
    <ion-label color="primary">Label</ion-label>
    <ion-label> Value</ion-label>
  </ion-item>
  <ion-item>

    <ion-label color="primary">Label</ion-label>
    <ion-label><button ion-button round outline><ion-icon name="star"  color="primary"> </ion-icon></button>(Student)</ion-label>

    <ion-icon ios="ios-close" md="md-close"></ion-icon>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

thanks